# fetch result from db by percents

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working right now on laravel 5.0 project, I have table with leads and table with leads history, I have form that the user choose how much leads to pick up and percents of how many of them are new, leads that doesnt exist in leads history table are new, I am trying all day to figure it out and I cant find the solution, I hope somebody here have the answer

EDIT: I finally done it! my answer below the old method

My method (before the edit)

```
 static public function getLeads($input)
{

    self::$input = $input;

    $amount = !empty($input['amount']) ? $input['amount'] : null;

    $leads = Lead::where(function ($query) {

        $input = self::$input;

        $with_name = !empty($input['with_name']) ? (int)$input['with_name'] : null;
        $countries = !empty($input['country']) ? $input['country'] : null;
        $dateFrom = !empty($input['date_from']) ? $input['date_from'] : null;
        $dateTo = !empty($input['date_to']) ? $input['date_to'] : null;
        $percentSent = !empty($input['percent_first']) ? $input['percent_first'] : null;
        $percentNotSent = !empty($input['percent_second']) ? $input['percent_second'] : null;

        if (isset($with_name) && $with_name === 2) {
            $query->where('full_name', '!=', '');
        }

        if (isset($with_name) && $with_name === 3) {
            $query->where('full_name', '!=', '');
            $query->where('email', '!=', '');
        }

        if (isset($countries)) {
            $query->whereIn('country', $countries);
        }

        if (isset($dateFrom)) {
            $query->where('date', '>=', $dateFrom);
        }

        if (isset($dateTo)) {
            $query->where('date', '<=', $dateTo);
        }

        if (isset($percentSent) && $percentSent >= 1) {
            //precent of sent
            $total = self::$input['amount'];
            $percentSent = $percentSent / 100;
            $total = $percentSent * $total;
            $total = round($total);
            //the new total is number of old leads
        }

    })->limit($amount)->get(['phone'])->toArray();

    return $leads;
}
```

The new Method:

```
static public function getLeads($input)
{

    self::$input = $input;

    $amount = !empty($input['amount']) ? $input['amount'] : null;
    $percentSent = !empty($input['percent_first']) ? $input['percent_first'] : null;
    $percentNotSent = !empty($input['percent_second']) ? $input['percent_second'] : null;

    $total = $amount;
    $percentSent = $percentSent / 100;
    $total = $percentSent * $total;
    $total = round($total);

    $leads = Lead::where(function ($query) {

        $input = self::$input;
        $with_name = !empty($input['with_name']) ? (int)$input['with_name'] : null;
        $countries = !empty($input['country']) ? $input['country'] : null;
        $dateFrom = !empty($input['date_from']) ? $input['date_from'] : null;
        $dateTo = !empty($input['date_to']) ? $input['date_to'] : null;
        $amount = !empty($input['amount']) ? $input['amount'] : null;

        $percentSent = !empty($input['percent_first']) ? $input['percent_first'] : null;
        $percentNotSent = !empty($input['percent_second']) ? $input['percent_second'] : null;
        $total = $amount;
        $percentSent = $percentSent / 100;
        $total = $percentSent * $total;
        $total = round($total);


        if (isset($with_name) && $with_name === 2) {
            $query->where('full_name', '!=', '');
        }

        if (isset($with_name) && $with_name === 3) {
            $query->where('full_name', '!=', '');
            $query->where('email', '!=', '');
        }

        if (isset($countries)) {
            $query->whereIn('country', $countries);
        }

        if (isset($dateFrom)) {
            $query->where('date', '>=', $dateFrom);
        }

        if (isset($dateTo)) {
            $query->where('date', '<=', $dateTo);
        }

        if($total == $amount){
            $query->where('lead_history.time', '!=', '');
        }

    })->leftJoin('lead_history', 'lead_history.lead_id', '=', 'leads.id')
        ->groupBy('leads.id')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(lead_history.lead_id) <= ' . $total)
        ->orderBy('leads.date')
        ->limit($amount)->get(['*'])->toArray();

    dd($leads);

    return $leads;

}
```

Thanks all!